# Python Get Request With Bearer Token. Error: "Caused by SSLError"

Tags: python, ssl, bearer-token

I am in the process of creating a Python script that retrieves JSON from a URL.

```
import requests

auth_token='my_unique_token_45345sdfwds'
hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token}

url = 'https://example.com/user/234sdf-234'
response = requests.post(url, headers=hed)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com/user', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /user/234sdf-234 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

I have a Powershell script that uses the same Bearer token without issue.

```
$token = "https://example.com/user/234sdf-234"
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token"; Accept = "application/json" }

$output = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Method Get `
  -Headers $headers `
  -ContentType: "application/json" `
  -Uri "https://example.com/user/234sdf-234"
$json_output
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: resolved --> had to add ", verify=False" within requests.get() to bypass the SSL cert check.

Comment: I would not call this "resolved". This instead worked around the issue in an insecure way. As for the real problem: nothing is known about the site you access. But the certificate might be issued by a CA which is in the windows trust store but not in the trust store used by Python.